# why the result is ascII not the chinese when I ues python2.5 to print the directory

Tags: python, character-encoding

the question is, I use the os moduel of python2.5 to get the file which has the specialize suffix name. but the result is ascII，not the chinese. why? who can help me? Thank you
the code is as follows:

```
#coding=utf-8
__author__ = 'Administrator'
import os
def listDirectory(directory, fileExtList):
    "get list of file info objects for files of particular extensions"
    fileList = [os.path.normcase(f) for f in os.listdir(directory)]
    fileList = [os.path.join(directory, f) for f in fileList if os.path.splitext(f)[1] != '' and os.path.splitext(f)[1] in fileExtList]
    return fileList
print listDirectory("g:\\", '.rar')
```

and the output is

```
g:\\11800 \xb9\xe2\xb7\xfc\xbc\xbc\xca\xf5\xbb\xf9\xb4\xa1\xd3\xeb\xbc\xbc\xc4\xdc\xa3\xa8\xcb\xf9\xd3\xd0\xd2\xb3\xa3\xa9.rar'
```

not the chinese

Comment: You are using a very old Pyhton... Please read  http://docs.python.org/2.6/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You apparently have omitted parts of your actual output, as printing a `list` wouldn't look like that)

`listDirectory` returns a list; when you `print` a non-string value, it will first convert it to its *representation* (the value returned by the `repr()` function for that value). Representation of strings in Python shows all non-ASCII values as backslash escapes. You likely want to call something along the lines of `print '\n'.join(listDirectory("g:\\", '.rar'))` if you want to *see* the actual printable characters; the strings returned by `listDirectory` *do* contain the correct characters, it is just the `print` statement you use that outputs them backslashed.

Comment: yes it is. i only pasted a part of the output. the key of the question is character-encoding.Thank you very much.